# How can I make Cygwin/perl load a specific library à la LD_LIBRARY_PATH/LD_RUN_PATH?

Tags: perl, dll, cygwin, ld, library-path

The issue I'm seeing is that the wrong version of a library gets loaded in a `perl` process running on Cygwin (1.7.15, current as of 09/2012).

Briefly, `perl` starts, does `use XML::LibXML`, which is the Perl interface to `libxml2`, Daniel Veillard's C library for XML, and the Perl/C glue then loads the C library. Now, there's two versions installed, an older one in `/usr/lib` and a more recent one in `/usr/local/lib` - a typical scenario. The Perl/C glue libary (`XML::LibXML`) is compiled against the newer version in `/usr/local/lib`. The Perl or Cygwin component responsable for loading libraries, however, picks up the older one. This triggers a warning by the Perl/C glue code, which rightly expects and demands the version it was compiled against. (It would still mostly work because of backward compatibility, but not quite as intended.)

One thing to note, on Cygwin it's not `lib/libxml2.so.2`, but rather `bin/cygxml2-2.dll`!

Here's the action copied from the screen:

```
MiLu@Dago: /tmp > export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin
MiLu@Dago: /tmp > export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/bin
MiLu@Dago: /tmp > ls -l /usr/bin/cygxml2-2.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 MiLu root 1096206  1. Mrz 2012  /usr/bin/cygxml2-2.dll
MiLu@Dago: /tmp > ls -l /usr/local/bin/cygxml2-2.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 MiLu None 3997813 21. Mai 22:35 /usr/local/bin/cygxml2-2.dll
MiLu@Dago: /tmp > perl -MXML::LibXML -e1
Warning: program compiled against libxml 208 using older 207
Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20800,
                 but runtime libxml2 is older 20708
```

I'm not sure how the C library `cygxml2-2.dll` (standard name `libxml2`) gets loaded.

Here's the `ldd` output for the Perl/C glue library:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.dll
    ntdll.dll       => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/ntdll.dll (0x774a0000)
    kernel32.dll    => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll (0x756c0000)
    KERNELBASE.dll  => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KERNELBASE.dll (0x76750000)
    cygwin1.dll     => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
    cygssp-0.dll    => /usr/bin/cygssp-0.dll (0x6af50000)
>>> cygxml2-2.dll   => /usr/local/bin/cygxml2-2.dll (0x63fc0000) <<<
    cygz.dll        => /usr/bin/cygz.dll (0x6a900000)
    cyggcc_s-1.dll  => /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-1.dll (0x6ca60000)
    cygiconv-2.dll  => /usr/bin/cygiconv-2.dll (0x6c390000)
    cygperl5_14.dll => /usr/bin/cygperl5_14.dll (0x6b8a0000)
    cygcrypt-0.dll  => /usr/bin/cygcrypt-0.dll (0x6d3d0000)
    ???             => ??? (0x520000)
```

As you can see, the newer library is correctly located, as would happen on UNIX. But `ldd` is not the actual process, which might use a different lookup mechanism.

Using `strace perl … | grep -i cygxml` shows no output.

It seems to me that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` are ignored. Because if not why do I get the version mismatch warning?

Is the library loading mechanism specific to `perl` or Cygwin? How does it work? How do I make `perl` or Cygwin load the proper library?

[One suspicion I have is that `perl` residing in `/usr/bin`, it will *first* look for libraries in `/usr/bin`, its binarie's directory, thus following the Windows convention rather than the UNIX convention.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In writing Alien::Base I needed to directly dlopen specific libraries using DynaLoader. You can read the code [here](https://github.com/jberger/Alien-Base/blob/master/lib/Alien/Base.pm) but the quick and dirty should be simply

```
require DynaLoader;
DynaLoader::dl_load_file( $library_path, 0x01 )
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding `DynaLoader::dl_load_file( '/usr/local/bin/cygxml2-2.dll', 0x01 )` does get rid of the warning. An explicit load instruction does the job, no surprise. It shouldn't be required, though. It still looks like either a feature or a malfunction in Perl or Cygwin to me. Not sure how it is supposed to work and where it goes wrong if indeed it does go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

cygwin does support LD_LIBRARY_PATH; try checking that it's set as you expect at the beginning of your script:

```
BEGIN { print "LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}.\n" }
```

Comment: Thanks. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set correctly. Had to be as per the `export` command preceding the `perl` command. The problem must be elsewhere.